Unable to start MS SQL image 2019 on docker windows : error failed to create shim task
I am trying to run a mssql container on windows following this https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server
I have managed to successfully download the image using docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
But when I try to run the image using the command
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<your_strong_password>" -p 1433:1433 --name sqlserver --hostname sqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
I get the following error

8ebb0c1ff1a193c57054a67c5d83185e62be2682bad033455c924739877ade68
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: invalid rootfs: stat /var/run/desktop-containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/8ebb0c1ff1a193c57054a67c5d83185e62be2682bad033455c924739877ade68/D:\Docker/vfs/dir/a04b98296e4dc498e5b347a08d39caaac1041fdfbdb11e4acc246a4fd4c305c2: no such file or directory: unknown.

I have also tried adding the -v ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data  but with no success.
My docker is installed on D drive and the docker engine settings are following due to another project.
{
"builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "data-root": "D:\\Docker",
  "experimental": false
}

I have tried changing it to only "data-root: D:\\Docker" but same issue persists.
I am using docker desktop with linux containers setting.

Aside... SA_PASSWORD has been deprecated for some years now, you should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation on Docker hub.

By changing your data-root you may well have encountered Changing Data-Root on windows causes startup failure. #11870

I have tried with MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as well. the data-root issue i think is an old one as I have been using docker in D drive for quite a while now for a project and it starts up without any issues

I recommend you to build your own image, it's not any hard, and if it's Windows you have a lot more functionality than the Linux version. Microsoft has abandoned their 2019 Windows image, so here's a tutorial I wrote to create your own (I don't include here the steps because there's not enough space): https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7093/install-sql-server-install-oracle-powershell-windows-containers/
